# Calling MySQL SP's with In & Out Params in VB .Net

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

Mysql stored proc is

---

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `Check1`(
  IN     P_Name          VARCHAR(50)
 ,OUT    P_Id            INT
)
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO Company
    (Name, Expiry, CreatedDate, Active)
  VALUES
    (P_Name, 90, NOW(), 1);        

  SET P_Id = @@identity;

END
```

---

Company TABLE has

- CompanyID
- Name
- CreateDate
- Active

as various columns

I need use VB .Net to call this procedure, insert value into the database and get the ID (primary key - company ID).

Whenever I insert a row, I need to retrieve the ID. Right now, I am able only to insert the row, but don't know how to call a SP with both input and output parameters from VB.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Direction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.direction.aspx) member of OleDbParameter.